# Which event fires when you click outside an editable ComboBox and cause it to close?

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox

It doesn't seem to be LostFocus. That event fires sometimes, but not every time you perform the action. Any Clues?

Comment: thks for the Quick response Pedro, but I'm looking for the one causing the Dropdown to close i.e. it's precursor

Comment: Look in to a tool called "snoop" you can attach it to your app and it can show you every wpf event that fires when you do an action.

Comment: I've changed my answer, see if it fits your needs now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are refering to the dropdown part closing when you say *"and cause it do close"*, the answer would be the [`ComboBox.DropDownClosed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.combobox.dropdownclosed) event.

In my tests the one that occurs right before that is [`UIElement.MouseLeave`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.mouseleave) event. Although the documentation says this event *"occurs when the mouse pointer leaves the bounds of this element"* (and it really does, when the dropdown part isn't open), this event is fired when you click outside the ComboBox with a dropdown opened, and just after that you get the `ComboBox.DropDownClosed` event.

Comment: thks Pedro - after testing MouseLeave, it is the one! Strange and very misleading though. I would have expected the event to fire whenever the boudaries of the control were left - dropdown open or not - and without clicking.

Comment: Tested Snoop too - it catches a MouseDown on the Combobox if you click somewhere else.